# Python import works on one computer but not on another (same Ubuntu OS)

Tags: python, import

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (focal). On Machine A my Python import works, but on the other (Machine B) it doesn't. `my_lib.py` is in the `library` folder. On both I've tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/library")
import my_lib
```

Which doesn't work on Machine B.  On Machine B I've also tried:

```
import importlib
my_lib = importlib.import_module("/absolute/path/to/library/our_lib")
```

Which reuslts in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/absolute/path/to/library/our_lib`. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the first approach doesn't work on one and not the other, and why the second approach doesn't work?

Comment: The short answer is presumably that the path is different or non-existent on machine B but the better answer is that it's a bad idea to do it this way. You may be able to use venvs and pip to install library into your environment or package it properly via some other method (e.g. poetry).

Comment: I'm fairly certain the path is correct. Regardless of whether it's a bad idea I'd quite like to know why it doesn't work on one of the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself. In `my_lib.py` I was importing a few modules, one of which was not installed on Machine B which was resulting in `my_lib.py` not being imported. It was installed on Machine A and hence it was all fine on that machine. Adding a `try...except` for the imports in `my_lib.py` made this obvious and hopefully means this won't happen again.